# Finding minimum variance based on combinations of binning in python

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I am looking to use a loop to iterate through all combinations of binning a variable before doing a group by. Example data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'age': [23,54,47,38,37,21,27,72,25,36],
                   'score':[28,38,47,27,37,26,28,48,27,47]})
df.head()

    id  age score
0   1   23  28
1   2   54  38
2   3   47  47
3   4   38  27
4   5   37  37
```

And then manually creating bins like so:

```
bins = [20,50,70,80]
labels = ['-'.join(map(str,(x,y))) for x, y in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]
df["age_bin"] = pd.cut(df["age"], bins = bins,labels = labels)
```

Finally calculating the average variance for that bin combination:

```
df.groupby("age_bin").agg({'score':'var'}).mean()
```

How can I loop through all combinations of bins, with a minimum bin size of 10 and but with no restrictions on the number of bins and assuming they do not have to be the same size?

e.g.

```
      bins              mean
0   [20, 50, 70, 80]    82.553571
1   [20, 70, 80]        74.611111
2   [20, 30, 60, 80]    35.058333
```

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Comment: As you pose the problem, there are far too many possible combinations to try via brute force. That is you could try cuts at [10, 11, ... 90, (10, 20), (10, 21), ... (10, 20, 30), (10, 20, 31)...] . It's just not possible to try them all. You can look into descent optimization methods like simulated annealing for instance.